# Email escalation for queues in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am running ActiveMQ Artemis on my machine and I would like to set up email escalation for queues that breach when the number of pending messages exceeds a certain limit. Is there any plugin or built-in feature that can help me achieve this? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

After days of research I have found that we can achieve this by using Advisory Queue. I am curious that this is important feature. There will be the other build-in or best approach than this one that I couldn't get across with.

Answer (score 2):

The broker itself won't send emails. Email alerts are generally implemented as part of a broader monitoring solution.

For example, you can configure the broker with [a metrics plugin](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/metrics.html) like the [Prometheus plugin](https://github.com/rh-messaging/artemis-prometheus-metrics-plugin). Once the broker is configured properly then you can configure Prometheus or even Grafana to send email alerts based on thresholds for all kinds of different situations. It's very flexible and powerful.

Of course, you could also set up your own simple monitoring mechanism using the [management API](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html) or you could integrate a commercial JMX monitoring tool (e.g. Nagios, AppDynamics, etc.).

I would recommend against using an Advisory Queue. This is a feature specifically implemented for OpenWire clients which came from ActiveMQ "Classic." It's not a general purpose monitoring solution.